# Linearization of Drag Equation

Tags: calculus

Working on a homework problem having to do with linearization of a nonlinear drag equation and am a little lost.

Heres the problem:

A drag force D is in general a nonlinear function of an object’s speed `v` that can be written in the form:

$D(v) = bv + cv^2$ + higher order [monomial] terms

where b, c, etc. are drag coefficients that depend on an object’s size and surface texture, the fluid medium’s density and viscosity, and other physical properties of the system.

Show that the linearization of $L_D(v)$ of $D(v)$ at $V = 0$ $L_D(v) = bv$

I am aware of the linearization formula $L(x) = f(a) + f ' (a) (x - a)$ but I only have really applied it in situations where I have a graph and specific points I am approximating. I tried to plug in the derivative of the $bv + cv^2$ equation and original equation into this but I have yet to get anything close to $L_D(v) = bv$

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: You have

\begin{align}
L_{D}(v) &= D(0) + D'(0)(v-0)
\end{align}

Can you compute  $D(0)$ and $D'(0)$?

Comment: Ah ok yes I can, I had tunnel vision on the equation. Thank you